# How can I add Status code to an Error?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, afnetworking, nserror

I have a 'JSON' data with different status codes, as shown in the image, I'm using 'AFHTTPSessionManager', And if we call the API I get 200 as success code, Apart from that in my response object I have status codes So I want to do different operations based on the status codes, For this I have written code like this..

```
-(void)validateOTP:(NSString *)OTP andUserID:(NSString *)userID withCompletion:(void(^)(NSDictionary* dictionary, NSError* error))completion   
{

    UTValidateOTPRequest *request = [UTValidateOTPRequest validateOTPRequestWithOTP:OTP andUserID:userID];

    NSDictionary *paramDict = [request dictionaryRepresentation];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self postRequestToResouce:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ValidateOTP",kServerCommonEndPoint] arguments:paramDict successHandler:^(NSDictionary *response) {

        NSNumber *statusCode = response[kStatusCodeKey];

        if (statusCode.integerValue == UTStatusCodeSuccess) {
            completion(response, nil);
        }

        else {
            NSError *error = [NSError mapStatusCodeToError:statusCode.integerValue details:response];

            completion(nil, error);

        }
    } errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        NSError *newError = [NSError mapStatusCodeToError:error.code details:error.userInfo];

        completion(nil, newError);

    }];

    [self addDataTask:task];

}
```

As you can see, even inside success handler I'm passing error and calling a category method we have created.

```
NSError *error = [NSError mapStatusCodeToError:statusCode.integerValue details:response];
```

This method implemented as follows

```
+ (NSError *)mapStatusCodeToError: (NSInteger)statusCode details:(NSDictionary*) errorInfo
{
    NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    NSString *domain = [bundleIdentifier stringByAppendingString:kErrorDomainKey];
    NSString *errorMessage = nil;
    if (errorInfo[kErrorMessageKey] && ![errorInfo[kErrorMessageKey] isEqualToString:kEmptyString]) {
        errorMessage = errorInfo[kErrorMessageKey];
    }
    else{
        // use common message
        errorMessage = kInternetNotAvailableMessage;
    }
    NSDictionary *userInfo = @{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:NSLocalizedString(errorMessage, nil)};
    NSLog(@"User INFO : %@",userInfo);

    NSError *internetUnavailableError = [NSError errorWithDomain:domain
                                                            code:NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet
                                                        userInfo:userInfo];

    NSLog(@"Error Code : %ld",(long)internetUnavailableError.code);
    return internetUnavailableError;
}
```

Here I want to use the statusCode that I'm passing as parameter to this method so that I can get that status code where I'm calling this method

```
[[UTServerManager sharedInstance] validateOTP:self.enterOTPText.text andUserID:self.userId withCompletion:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
       // Here I want to get the status code of error not like -1009 , but what ever statusCode that I'm getting from the API response. 
    }];
```

So in this method can I get the response status code if it is not success code means as you see  in the image in the first response is success and remaining are error responses.

And I know that I can use the statusCode in the category method but I dont know how to use it, If I store this status-Code in the category method for error as above , that I'm passing as a parameter to the methods then I can call them where ever I require  How to get this [image]?

And my restriction is I should these methods only but I have to add the response status code to error ??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing a userInfo dict to the NSError.  You could add to this dictionary prior to creating the NSError you are returning, and then later it would be available in the NSError callback.